# Is there a way to stop recording from Android HAL or Framework?

Tags: android, audio

Is there a way to notify app from Audio framework/AudioHAL that you can stop the audio recording session ? (The reverse way)

I understand the android design,  Audio Framework and HAL should obeys the App and keep the audio capture session open until app calls stopRecording(), but is there a way out , where I can return some read() error

I checked the android documentation :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#read(byte[], int, int)

read() Returns
int the number of bytes that were read or ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION if the object wasn't properly initialized, or ERROR_BAD_VALUE if the parameters don't resolve to valid data and indexes. The number of bytes will not exceed sizeInBytes.

When I return ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION / ERROR_BAD_VALUE will it cause the app to stop sending reads and close the session ?